# Trigger method if counters have a particular value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, triggers

I have used counter_culture gem to be able to keep track of a Order has_many Item association. I have the following counters in my Item model:

```
counter_culture :order, :column_name => Proc.new {|model| model.pending_review? ? 'pending_review_count' : nil }
counter_culture :order, :column_name => Proc.new {|model| model.reviewed? ? 'review_count' : nil }
counter_culture :order, :column_name => Proc.new {|model| model.failed? ? 'fail_count' : nil }
```

I would like to be able to call a specific method of my Order, whenever:

```
pending_review_count + fail_count == total_count
```

or

```
review_count + fail_count == total_count
```

Right now, every time an Item gets updated, I check the values of the counters and do the comparison, but this seems a little bit overkill. Is there any way to set a trigger for the mentioned conditions in Rails?

Comment: My guess is you're doing it in a `before_save` callback and I think that approach is fine. I dont know of any Rails API that would let you set these sorts of triggers, and even if it existed I cant see how it would be done without doing a comparison on every save. The only difference would be that the comparison happened behind the scenes.

Comment: I am actually doing the comparison on an after_update.